# HTML Form onclick event doesn't call javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick

I would like to create a dynamic form, adding inputs into the form by pressing a button (or an image)
when I put the code directly on the onclick event

```
alert("Hello");
```

it works... however, it doesn't when I try to call a javascript function... Even If I call the  simple function hello(); (as well with add() )

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function add() {
    var container = document.createElement("div"); 
    container.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='email'><br/>";
    document.getElementById('emails').appendChild(container);
}
function hello() {
    alert("Hello"); 
}
​</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="valid.php" method="POST">
    <div id="emails">
        <input type='text' name='email' value=''/><br />
    </div>
    <img width="50px" src="myimage.jpg" onclick='add();'/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone manage to spot why ?

Comment: Where do you actually call the function?

Comment: I see no place where you specify `hello` as onclick event handler

Comment: Seems to work here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k9g5e/

Comment: calling hello() or add(), it doesn't work...

Comment: Both work fine in @j08691's example.

Comment: I'm aware that it works on jsfiddle... however it doesn't when written to a file and opened on safari through MAMP

Comment: Have you used any dev tools to check the console for errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it have some kind of special character before:

```
 </script>.
```

I just copied and pasted [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eitjh).
Look the first character in the 13th line

Comment: Damn !  it did not appeared on my editor... Thanks it fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

I copied this into a nice little jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/dr9hG/

I also changed the name from just `"email"` to `"email[]"` so that you can access all of them by array on the page this submits to.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I wasn't at this part yet, but still helpful